# STL iterators: container.end()

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

I was reading some docs about STL and it was written there that the `end()` function returns an iterator of the byte **next to** the last element of the container.

And I wonder, what if the container occupies the very last bytes of the whole available memory. What will happen then?

Comment: A pointer is a kind of iterator, not the other way around.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley can you please tell me why this is so? I'm a beginner...

Comment: I'm just being nit-picky.  What I was getting at is that there are many types of iterators, not just pointers.  So it is not the case that "iterators are pointers".  *Some* iterators are pointers, and some are not.  Now the converse, "pointers are iterators", that is true, or at least, that's what I meant to imply.  However, that's actually not true.  Some pointers are not iterators, some are just used as a type of reference.  So I was mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ memory model guarantees that you can always form a pointer to the element after the last element of an array. If there is none, either the system won't let you allocate an object at this location or it would wrap around. Also, note that this is a potential problem for arrays as other containers can use iterator types which deal with the past the end position in some other suitable form: they fully control how the increment operation work.

Comment: does this mean that I won't be let to make an array, which occupies the whole available at the moment memory, right? At least one byte must be left? Do I get it right?

Comment: @Kolyunya: The design of C++ doesn't prevent it, but most OSes still won't allow it.

Comment: @Kolyunya: Say you were working on a 16-bit embedded system and you made an array that had a 16-bit integer at position 0xFFFE. Add one integer (2 bytes) and it wraps around to become 0x0000. If you do a simple comparison of iterators they are both 0 and i == end(). All is well.

Answer (score 3):

An end iterator (at least figuratively) points just *past* the end of the container. The valid items in the container go from `*container.begin()` through `*container.end()-1`.

In other words, you can compare some other iterator to the end iterator to see if they'r equal (which tells you that you've reached the end of the items in the container), but you can *not* dereference that end iterator (i.e., you must not attempt to access an item that it refers to).

Edit: Sorry, kind of misunderstood the question: well, if the container actually used the last byte of memory (rare/unlikely, but theoretically possible) you'd typically see the address wrap around to the beginning of memory, assuming it was an iterator that really worked in terms of address, of course. In such a case, you'd typically see it turn into a `0` address, which can still be distinguished from any valid address (i.e., `0` will convert to a null pointer, which can't be a valid pointer).

In a typical case, however, it's likely that such a thing just wouldn't be allowed to happen. Just for example, on most 32-bit systems, the user is restricted to using the first 2 or 3 gigabytes of address space, and the upper addresses are reserved for the operating system.

Comment: The question is asking what happens if there are no more memory addresses though. So the iterator points to memory that does not physically exist.

Comment: What if the last element points to the last byte in memory. What will .end() point to (at least figuratively) then?

Comment: @Borgleader: nothing, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: If the situation described in your third paragraph were possible, wouldn't that break all the inequality operators?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Given that an iterator may only support equal/not-equal, there's not necessarily anything to break. Even if it does support inequality comparison, they're free to use other means to make it work (e.g., subtract 1 from each pointer before comparing).